# Temporarily disable kubernetes liveness probes for a pod

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, heap-memory, kubectl, kubernetes-health-check

I have a NodeJS app running inside a k8s pod and I want to take a heap dump of it.

In NodeJS taking a heap dump is [time-consuming and blocks the main thread](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/diagnostics/memory/using-heap-snapshot#warning), so the pod is not able to respond to k8s liveness probes and is occasionally SIGKILLed.

Is there a way to prevent such behavior? F.e. stop liveness probes for a pod in runtime for let's say 10 minutes until a dump is ready.
Or are there any known practices to handle cases similar to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [the open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57187) in k8s with the request similar to mine.

In the end I replaced the http probe with [the exec probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) to conditionally check some temporary file for existence:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -f "/tmp/liveness-status" ] || curl -f http://localhost:8081/status >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So to run some long-running task (such as taking a dump) on a pod I should at first create some file:

1. `kubectl exec <pod> – touch /tmp/liveness-status`
2. *take an action*
3. `kubectl exec <pod> – rm /tmp/liveness-status`

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to "pause" `livenessProbe`. Therefore, the options to consider are:

1. Adapt `livenessProbe` parameters to handle this `10 min` down scenario; e.g. increase `failureThreshold` and `periodSeconds`
2. Solve it at the application / container level; e.g. you can have a second process running which replies to `/health` check
3. Solve it at the sidecar level; e.g. you can have a sidecar container which will handle `/health` check

Comment: As the lifeness probe does have a sense it shouldn't be set higher and higher as needed. Best option in my opinion is 2 with the approach of @star67.